# how to update a table column with values within?

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to update a column with some cells are full and some of are blank.
i have a code like this and it is not working.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    t1.type_name = t2.type_name
FROM   table_name t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT progID, type_name 
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE type_name <>''
) t2 ON t1.progID = t2.progID
WHERE t1.type_name <>''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
UPDATE table_name t1 
INNER JOIN (select distinct progID, type_name from table_name where type_name <>'') t2 
ON t1.progID = t2.progID 
SET t1.type_name = t2.type_name
WHERE t1.type_name <> ''
```

You don't need the FROM clause.
But are you sure that you want to update the type_name column that has a value? 
 Maybe change the last condition to:

```
WHERE t1.type_name IS NULL
```

Comment: i changed where statement as you say. where t1.type_name =""

Answer (score 0):

I would be wary of using `select distinct` in the subquery because you can still get duplicates.  Just use `group by`, so you are guaranteed that the subquery generates only one row per `ProgId`:

```
UPDATE table_name t JOIN
       (SELECT progID, MAX(type_name) as type_name
        FROM table_name 
        WHERE type_name <> ''
        GROUP BY progID
       ) tt
       ON t.progID = tt.progID
    SET t.type_name = tt.type_name
FROM table_name t1
WHERE t1.type_name <> '';
```